# ANGULAR 5 & LARAVEL5.5

Tags: angular, laravel-5, angular5, laravel-5.5

After "ng build" in my angular app (its located in resources/assets/src/my-angular-app/ ), when I open my laravel project I see the pages, and all works, but when I reload the page, it's say "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found." I know why it say :) but I don't know what i can do to fix that.

can you help me? any advice or some link? thnks :)

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: No, best way is to write apis with laravel and use these with angular.

Comment: I don't know anything about laravel and its templates but I assume that a laravel template should be included at the root of your angular app. Find your index.html (index.php?) where your app root is defined or in app.component.ts, etc.

Comment: I tried, and it not works, so I just want to know is it possible?

Comment: just fixed with laravel routing :)

Answer (score -1):

If you want use laravel and angular >= 2 :

**Laravel is PHP Web Application Framework.
 Angular 5 or just Angular is Popular Front End Framework for creating a client-side application. so  we can interact with each other via an API.**

(each of them in a separate project not include angular5 in laravel project or Reversing! )